# For which $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ is there a $\sigma\in S_{14}$ such that $|\sigma|=n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

For which $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ is there a $\sigma\in S_{14}$ (the group of permutations on $\{1,2,\dots,14\}$) such that $|\sigma|=n$ (where $|\sigma|$ is the order of $\sigma$)?

I know you could just enumerate all elements of $S_{14}$, but that would take a very long time. Are there any more elegant approaches?

Answer (score 2):

The order of a cycle is the length of the cycle, and every permutation is a product of commuting cycles. Thus the possible orders are all least common multiples of sets of positive integers whose sums are less than or equal to 14.

By hand I found 29 distinct combinations yielding 13, 11, 22, 33, 9, 18, 36, 45, 8, 24, 40, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 84, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 60, 4, 12, 3, 6, 2. The identity is also of order 1, so that makes  30 different orders.

EDIT: As Derek pointed out, I missed one. The culprit is cycle type $(7,5,2)$, which is of order 70.

Comment: This makes the problem seem a little bit more manageable, but there are still 135 possible integer partitions of $14$. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @user197402 I didn't realize it was necessary to actually write them all out. You can at restrict your attention to partitions where all parts are powers of distinct primes or 1. I found all of the relevant ones on paper just now by hand and I count 33. Though I wouldn't stake my life on the 33 being exact, it's close.

Comment: @user197402 realized I counted some whose sum was larger than 14. Current count is 29.

Comment: @user197402 I posted the orders I found. If you find some different number, don't stress too much over it because nobody should completely trust anybody's hand calculations.

Comment: I cheated and used a computer. There are $31$. Everything on your list is correct, but there is missing order.

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks for verifying. I'm shocked I missed only one.